# How to calculate $\frac {d}{dx}$ ($\int_{1}^{x^2} \sqrt{ \ln(t)}\,dt$), when $|x|>1$

Tags: integration, derivatives

How do I calculate $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{1}^{x^2} \sqrt{\ln(t)}\,dt \right)$, when $|x|>1$ ?

After thinking about this I concluded that the operation $\frac {d}{dx}$ gets us back the original function. so I said that the derivative is: 
$$\frac {d}{dx} \left(\int_{1}^{x^2} \sqrt{\ln(t)}\,dt \right) = \sqrt{\ln(x^2)} - \sqrt{\ln(1)},$$
but for somehow this answer is wrong. What is my mistake?

Comment: The first formula here does it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign
It's even easier in your case as two of the three terms are zero.

Comment: @Frank that certainly seems like a laser cannon for a fly when the FTC and chain rule will do it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{1}^{x^2} \sqrt{ln(t)}\,dt\right) = 2x\sqrt{\ln(x^2)}.$$

Comment: You should probably also quote the chain rule, since you're using it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You applied the fundamental theorem of calculus in the wrong way.

Assuming that $F(x)$ is a primitive for $f(x)$, the derivative of $F(x^2)$ is not $f(x^2)$, it is $2x\cdot f(x^2)$.

If assume $x>1$ (the other case is not much different) by setting $t=u^2$ we have:
$$ \int_{1}^{x^2}\sqrt{\log t}\,dt = \int_{1}^{x} 2u \sqrt{\log u^2}\,du \tag{1}$$
so the derivative with respect to $x$ is given by $\color{red}{2x\sqrt{2\log x}}.$